# Can a smart contract have multiple addresses?

Tags: contract-design, addresses

Can a smart contract have multiple addresses? And I am not asking whether a smart contract can have other smart-contracts. What I am asking is, theoretically can a smart contract have multiple addresses. Lets say there is a smart contract for a game where you choose the outcome of an event. There is outcome A, B and C. can a smart contract theoretically have an address for each outcome where I send tokens to the outcome address if I want to choose it? This is without having other smart contracts?
If this is not possible in Ethereum can a blockchain be designed such that this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's doable. There are multiple ways to achieve it. One which is interesting is so-called Diamond pattern [EIP-2535: Diamonds, Multi-Facet Proxy](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535)

> A diamond is a contract with external functions that are supplied by
> contracts called facets.
>
> Facets are separate, independent contracts that can share internal
> functions, libraries and state variables.

You can build one controller contract and facets for each outcome.

Comment: Is there any tutorial or example how to do this thing?